# Replacement for jxDBCon?

Tags: java, jdbc

[jxDBCon](http://jxdbcon.sourceforge.net/) is JDBC driver framework which implements generic parts of a JDBC driver. However it is unmaintained and implements only things in older, not current, JDBC.

Are there any other libraries that help with implementation of JDBC drivers but that support current JDBC specification/interfaces?